# Dynamically showing ElDialog component

Tags: vuejs3, element-plus

The normal way we need to show el-dialog is like this

```
<template>
...
    <el-dialog :visible="isVisible" />
...
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ElDialog } from 'element-plus';

const isVisible = ref(false);
</script>
```

Is there any way to show dialog directly from js file like

```
import mywrapper from 'utils/my-libs';

function abc() {
    mywrapper.show('Title', 'Description');
}
```

Where mywrapper have some code that dynamically loads el-dialog html. How I can achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a use case for an event bus.

Using the event bus from [@vueuse](https://vueuse.org/core/useEventBus) you can make an emit function in some .js file:

**util.js**

```js
import { useEventBus } from "@vueuse/core";

const bus = useEventBus("vue-use-event-bus");

const emit = () => {
  console.log("emitting...");
  bus.emit("showDialog", { title: "MyTitle", description: "My Description" });
};

export default emit;
```

Then have the component listen to the same event bus

**dialogComponent.vue**

```js
import { ref } from "vue";
import { useEventBus } from "@vueuse/core";

const title = ref("");
const description = ref("");
const isVisible = ref(false);

// use same bus
const bus = useEventBus("vue-use-event-bus");

const show = (payload) => {
  isVisible.value = true;
  title.value = payload.title;
  description.value = payload.description;
};

// listen to an event
bus.on((event, payload) => {
  if (event === "showDialog") {
    show(payload);
  }
});
```

Then wherever you need to, emit the event

**someComponent.vue**

```js
<script setup>
import emit from "../util.js";
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="emit">Send emit from util.js</button>
</template>
```

[working sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/zen-johnson-0one9x?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A1%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A1%7D%5D)